# Google AMP loads Non cached version first which slows down the Page load

Tags: amp-html

Our Cached AMP pages are loading very slowly, I did some digging and found out that the Non Cached URL is loading (1.5 seconds) before the actual Cached URL is loaded.Can someone help me debug this or we can just disable loading the Non cached URL.[Here is an image of the HTTP calls its making](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppYlf.png)

Comment: AMPHTML issue [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues) to reach out to the developers of AMPHTML.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail (e.g. cached vs non-cached URLs). Your screenshot only shows the non-cached version.